# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute '_meta' error in Django

Tags: python, django, forms, view

I'm trying to make a webpage for signing up in django, but I can't get around this error:

```
from accounts.forms.forms import AuthForm, SignUpForm
```

File "C:\Users\tonik\OneDrive\Plocha\Python projects\chytry-lock-master\smartlock\accounts\forms\forms.py", line 7, in 
    class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
  File "C:\Users\tonik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 256, in **new**
    apply_limit_choices_to=False,
  File "C:\Users\tonik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 139, in fields_for_model
    opts = model._meta
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute '_meta'

my forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.forms.widgets import PasswordInput, TextInput


class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True, help_text='Required. Please enter a valid e-mail address.')
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True, widget=TextInput(attrs={'class': 'span2', 'placeholder': 'e-mail'}), help_text='Required. Please enter a valid e-mail address.')

    class Meta:
        model = UserCreationFormFields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')
        fields = "__all__"

class AuthForm(AuthenticationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = AuthenticationForm


        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(AuthenticationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

            for field in self.fields.values():
                field.error_messages = {'required': '{fieldname} is required'.format(fieldname=field.label)}

    username = forms.CharField(widget=TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'nickname'})),
    email = forms.CharField(widget=TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'e-mail'})),
    password = forms.CharField(widget=PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder':'password'}))
```

my views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from smartlock.forms import SignUpForm


def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            first_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=first_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            form = UserCreationForm()
            return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
```

Spent hours trying to fix this, still not sure whats wrong.

Comment: What is this line supposed to do? `model = UserCreationFormFields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')`?

Comment: A `model = ...` should always specify, well, a model, not a form, neither a list/tuple/... of fields.

Answer (score 0):

Change your signup form to this.
You cannot use a tuple or list for _meta see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/options/

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True, help_text='Required. Please enter a 
            valid e-mail address.')
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True, widget=TextInput(attrs={'class': 
            'span2', 'placeholder': 'e-mail'}), help_text='Required. Please 
            enter a valid e-mail address.')

    class Meta:
          model = UserCreationFormFields
          fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')
```